# Using generic value in v-slot:head

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I try to create a generic Bootstrap Vue Table Component. For the field label in HTML format, I try to do something such:

```html
<template v-for="field in fields" v-slot:head(field_name)>
  <span v-translate render-html="true" v-html="field.label"></span>
</template>
```

Here, my problem is, when I put v-slot:head(field_name), the field_name is not generic and it is accepting as a string. So when I write field.key to v-slot:head, I want it to check the value of field.key but not field.key as the value itself.

```html
<template v-for="field in fields" v-slot:head(field.key)>
   <span v-translate render-html="true" v-html="field.label"></span>
</template>
```

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for dynamic slots is:

```html
<template v-slot:[dynamicSlotName]>
  // ...
</template>
```

Applied to your case:

```html
<template v-for="field in fields" v-slot:[`head(${field.key})`]>
   <span v-translate render-html="true" v-html="field.label"></span>
</template>
```

Comment: When I do that, it asks "head" function to be existed: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.head is not a function"

Comment: if `head` is not a function, try `v-slot:[\`head(${field.key})\`]`. why do you have parentheses then?